# Typing a caught rejected promise return value

Tags: typescript, es6-promise, typescript-typings

I expect this code to compile:

```ts
function promiseCatchType(): Promise<[boolean, null]>
function promiseCatchType(): Promise<[null, string]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
      return resolve();
    } else {
      return reject();
    }
  })
    .then(() => [true, null])
    .catch(() => [null, 'error']);
}
```

But it throws me that error:

```
Type 'Promise<boolean[] | [any, string]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<[null, string]>'.
  Type 'boolean[] | [any, string]' is not assignable to type '[null, string]'.
    Type 'boolean[]' is missing the following properties from type '[null, string]': 0, 1
```

Here, I declare that my function can return two different kind of tuples, one in a successful case, the other on the unsuccessful case.

I want to handle my errors this way:

```ts
const [success, error] = await promiseCatchType();
if (error !== null) {
  // error is a string
  return 'An error occurred:' + error;
}

// Do something with `success`, if error is not null, then data must be of `boolean` type
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why not let errors be errors? Handle them in a `catch` block?

Comment: I made this for education purpose, I am trying to experience new patterns in personal projects, I wrote a few projects in Golang and I liked the way errors **had** to be handled. But yes indeed, errors remain errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- You're representing your return values as [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)... but for overloads, the implementation's signature does not count as one of the call signatures.  So the only call signature you're exposing is `function promiseCatchType(): Promise<[boolean, null]>`.  If you want to expose two call signatures, you could write `function promiseCatchType(): Promise<[boolean, null]>; function promiseCatchType(): Promise<[null, string]>;` and then write a general implementation that returns something like `Promise<[null, string] | [boolean, null]>`.  But:
- Overloads which only differ by return type are not generally useful.  There's no way for the compiler to tell which call signature `promiseCatchType()` should match, and in practice you'll always get the first one when you call it.  Instead, I'd forget about overloads and have a single signature that returns a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).
- Array literals like `[true, null]` tend to be inferred as arrays like `(boolean | null)[]` and not tuples.  There are different ways around this but one is to explicitly assert `[true, null] as [boolean, null]`.

This leads me to the following code:

```
function promiseCatchType(): Promise<[boolean, null] | [null, string]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
      return resolve();
    } else {
      return reject();
    }
  })
    .then(() => [true, null] as [boolean, null])
    .catch(() => [null, 'error'] as [null, string]);
}
```

Another issue arises when you call it.  Destructuring the array into separate `success` and `error` will make the compiler lose track of the correlation between them.  The compiler is generally unable to see union-type values as correlated with each other.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more information.  If you check that `error === null`, the compiler will not understand that this makes `success` a `boolean` and not a `null`.

```
async function fooBad() {
  const [success, error] = await promiseCatchType();
  if (error !== null) {
    return 'An error occurred:' + error;
  } else {
    success; // boolean | null ?!
  }
  return;
}
```

Instead, you can treat the un-destructured tuple as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), and only pull out its members after testing.  That works but might not be as idiomatic as you'd like:

```
async function foo() {
  const ret = await promiseCatchType();
  if (ret[1] !== null) {
    const error = ret[1];
    return 'An error occurred:' + error;
  } else {
    const success = ret[0]; // boolean
  }
  return;
}
```

In fact, I'd be inclined to refactor away from a tuple and to a more obvious discriminated union like `{success: true, value: boolean} | {success: false, errorMessage: string}` and not destructure at all.  But that starts getting further afield of the question, so I'll stop there.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wLYwM4FMDCAhlBABYAqAnsrgBQCUAXIgArpZ4A8A2gEZxwANrkJgANIjAhBggLqIAPom5SZE7FFQwwAc1kA+RAG8AUIkSpcUEKiRhcAd1bscdWpexCAbrgmWAVrjQ9IgAvIam5uYwwIi0ALLEpAB0qKIAJpgMiIbJAKwhkVHmlta2Friegj4MANxmUQC+iLiCeMYNxaU2SAFBUHWdiI0NjfRDyVCkuGC02eHKmiC+ktJyiITYyvxCIuKrMrLjxckQxGRzIQsqaxIA5Lio6Kh38pvKqoLqmtp69PUjRAmTaUSCIUCQWAIcECABChHS2SKEAQGmU2BAEAglWwEkez3koQ2DkIMCgKBceCIJAo1Do-waMTi+LgqEQAEJQkTPoUht1yncAIJIFlsuBYmyWdKMO6IADULSerPq5marXaRXMGKxONqiAA9PrEDthKJFAdBIgAPzs0YNflgAEmYHYUEQcHgaDwJDAARIhoosBo0phYmk8loTCualkKg0QbRWLuKzcACM8k53LWvOKgbRotDpTTshVUQdiCFIqVYolT1w0tlCtFpbVbVwHVzqPJ2ux2C2RKLAAYSwajSa9naSlYegCgA)

Comment: This helps me in an unimaginable way to understand what's going on underneath. This is awesome. As I said in a comment to this post, I tried this for educational purposes. So now is a great time to realize that it's the wrong way to handle errors, and that discriminated unions are more appropriate. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are two changes you have to make, one of which I understand, the other of which I frankly don't. :-)

1. You need to declare both external signatures, and then an implementation signature that supports both of them. Right now you just have a single external signature and an incompatible implementation signature.
2. You have to reassure TypeScript that `[true, null]` is `[boolean, null]`. I don't understand why. In infers `[true, null]` as `(boolean|null)[]` rather than `[boolean, null]`, even though it infers `[null, 'error']` as `[null, string]`, not `(null|string)[]`.

So:

```
function promiseCatchType(): Promise<[boolean, null]>;                 // 1
function promiseCatchType(): Promise<[null, string]>;                  // 1
function promiseCatchType(): Promise<[boolean, null]|[null, string]> { // 1
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
      return resolve();
    } else {
      return reject();
    }
  })
    .then(() => [true, null] as [boolean, null])
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− 2
    .catch(() => [null, 'error']);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wLYwM4FMDCAhlBABYAqAnsrgBQCUAXIgArpZ4A8A2gEZxwANrkJgANIjAhBggLoA+ANwAoUJFgIU7HAWJkqNBszaYdPKTInYoqGGADmClWujwkaU3iIkK1Ok1ZtLj4BYVEJCzkAH25Iqxs7R3lEAG9lRERUXCgQVCQwXAB3QM86WizsIQA3XAksgCtcaHpEAF5ktIyMmGBEWgBZYlIAOlRRABNMBkRk4YBWFs6ujKycvMzcSsEahhVlgF9EXEE8VPTljbWkBqaoXfOM-fP9+gfEYahSXDBaafbEbg2EC1STSOSIQjYAH8IQicSgmSyV7LYYQPSkX4tf6xMESADkuFQ6FQeKRKn2QA)